# How to isolate objects by removing some known points in an image in opencv c++

Tags: c++, opencv

this might be obvious but please pardon me because I am very new at this. I have a project to extract some rail tracks which I have done. The second part of the project is to detect the humans in the image, I have done that too but I also have the ground points in this image, since I have this ground points as a vector of points, i am trying to create a mask using this points and that where I am getting stuck. I first removed repeating points using the "unique" function, now I am trying to sort the points using a predefined "sort function but I keep getting an error. the sort code sample is:

```
struct contour_sorter // 'less' for contours
{
    bool operator ()(const vector<Point> &a,const vector<Point> &b )
    {
        Rect ra(boundingRect(a));
        Rect rb(boundingRect(b));
        // scale factor for y should be larger than img.width
        return ( (ra.x + 1000*ra.y) < (rb.x + 1000*rb.y) );
    }
};

vector<Point> requiredPoints;

unique(requiredPoints.begin(), requiredPoints.end() );
// apply it to the contours:
std::sort(requiredPoints.begin(), requiredPoints.end(), contour_sorter());
```

the error is:

> no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘cv::Point_’ to ‘const
>   std::vector >&’

is there a better way to achieve my goal? I just want to detect the objects, put each in a rectangle and find the distance to the camera. Right now I just have blobs from the morphological operation performed. Thank you

The image can be viewed through the link

[images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GkbrH.jpg)

Comment: Why do you want to sort the points, and also providing a sample input image would help

Comment: Because I pushed several points into the vector of points and they are not ordered...my thinking was that maybe if they are ordered I can use the "drawcontour" function. I have added a link to the image